# Is there an equivalent to C#'s string interpolation in Delphi/Lazarus Pascal?

Tags: c#, delphi, pascal

Is there an equivalent to C#'s string interpolation in Delphi/Object Pascal? I'm aware of a couple Object Pascal variants such as REMObjects Oxygene as well as PascalABC.Net having string interpolation but both are also CLI/.Net-framework based languages?

Example of C# String Interpolation:

```
double a = 3;
double b = 4;
Console.WriteLine($"Area of {a} and {b} is {0.5 * a * b}");
```

Comment: Your question body does nothing but repeat what you've already said in the title, which is not useful. Redundantly saying the same exact thing is just noise.Can you explain more clearly what you're trying to do, what you mean specifically by *string interpolation*, and ask a more specific question? People that don't know C# but know Delphi might be able to help if you more clearly stated what you're wanting. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time reading the [help] pages (especially [ask]) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: [C# string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated), and no, there is nothing like that in Delphi or Freepascal. The closest equivalent  is `SysUtils.Format()`

Comment: Thanks Remy! That's what I suspected after scouring the internet for an answer. I added an explanation of 'string interpolation' and sample code for those that might need a refresher and to appease others. I'm glad I could rely on the Stack Overflow's power-user base for a succinct answer. Cheers! :)

Comment: `Format('Area of %d and %d is %d', [a, b, (0.5 * a * b)]);`

Comment: @USauter, thank you, that's very C-like which works.  
`printf("Area of %d and %d is %d", a, b, (0.5 * a * b));`

Comment: @RemyLebeau, in the spirit of Pascal-derived languages, I just learned that PascalABC.Net  supports C#-like string interpolation as well, which might be too obvious with '.Net' in their name ;)   Oxygene supports double quotes which makes it look identical to C#:
`writeLn($"It's nice to meet you {fname}!");`
as where PascalABC.Net supports only single quotes: 
`writeLn($'It''s nice to meet you {fname}!');`

Comment: ...and I must say that PascalABC.net and Oxygene are a bit less pascal than what I prefer...

Answer (score 2):

No, there is nothing like [C# string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) in Delphi or FreePascal. The closest equivalent is [`SysUtils.Format()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format), eg:

```pascal
uses
  ..., SysUtils;

var
  a, b: Double;
begin
  a := 3.0;
  b := 4.0;
  WriteLn(Format('Area of %f and %f is %f', [a, b, 0.5 * a * b]));
  ...
end;
```